# Gitlab api to list only parent groups

Tags: gitlab

I am having few thousands of groups in GitLab and each group has one or more subgroups in them.

The /api/v4/groups is listing all the groups. Is there an API available just to filter and list only the parent groups?

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution.

Have to pass the below argument in api call

```
top_level_only=yes
```

This will ensure giving only the top level groups.

Happy to share knowledge